# Android battery pinout

Tags: adb, 5.0-lollipop, battery

I have an Lollipop EDC. That Android has battery with 6 pinouts. How to get information about battery pin-out via ADB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query get all information Android has about your battery by executing

```
adb shell dumpsys battery
```

Then you will get an output like this:

```
Current Battery Service state:
  AC powered: false
  USB powered: true
  Wireless powered: false
  Max charging current: 400000
  Max charging voltage: 5000000
  Charge counter: 1363859
  status: 2
  health: 2
  present: true
  level: 51
  scale: 100
  voltage: 3833
  temperature: 190
  technology: Li-ion
```

I don't know how and if it is possible to get other details on the battery such as the type number (e.g. for buying a replacement). If you require such information I would check if there is a tear-down video e.g. on https://iFixit.com for your device that includes such information.

Comment: How to find pinouts such as Pin1 = VCC, Pin2 = GND, Pin3 = BSI, Pin4 = Temperature and so on via ADB?

Comment: @koding I don't think that this information is stored anywhere electronically on-device. It is a fixed property of the phone and the used battery. Using the phone name and the battery type you may find this info somewhere on the net but AFAIK not on-device.

Comment: Thanks for point out.